# Is there a way to start a bash script after boot only when wlan0 is connected

Tags: bash, scripts

i want to start a bash script in ubuntu after boot. But the script should run first after wlan0 device is connected to my wifi.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start it at boot and let it wait until wlan0 is connected. You can check this via

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    # testing...
    LC_ALL=C nmcli -t -f DEVICE,STATE dev | grep -q "^wlan0:connected$"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        break
    else
        # not connected, sleeping for a second
        sleep 1
    fi
done

# now connected, run the script
```

Comment: great, works as a charme. thank you very much. note to other interested users: if your system language is not English you have to customize this part. "^wlan0:connected$"

Comment: Good catch! As mentioned in the man page of `nmcli` you can just start nmcli prepended by LC_ALL=C to avoid locale issues.

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu you can use upstart for this. Save the following as */etc/init/yourscript.conf*

```
start on net-device-up wlan0

exec  your_script
```

Comment: I thought about this too, but does that actually wait for wlan0 to be connected or just for the interface being "ready"?

Comment: Gave it a try and it runs 'your_script' once wlan0 is connected, so +1 for your answer.